# Weston dimming screensaver

Tags: wayland

I found that it is possible to totally blank the screen in Weston with the idle parameter, and wake it up again with input.

This is so far fine, but we are running a kiosk service, and want the screen to dim to save power, and when the screen is touched, then it will increase the backlight to 100% again.

I had hoped this was possible with an external screensaver, but as this is no-longer supported in Weston, what can I use then?

Comment: Maybe you can clarify your question by indicating what works and what does not. My tests indicates that `weston -i 10` dim the screen after 10s but `weston -i 10 --shell=hiosk-shell.so` does not. Oh, I see that you filed an issue : https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/weston/-/issues/750